# MySQL covariance computation on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, covariance

I have a single table MySQL database of financial transactions with the following schema:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| symbol_id       | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| timestamp       | timestamp(6)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| buy_sell        | char(1)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price           | decimal(10,6)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are 200 unique `symbol_id`s. Ultimately I want to be able to compute the running (over time) covariance of the price of all of these pairs.
Initially I can settle for just computing the covariance of a single pair and then I can iterate.

In order to compute a covariance I need two arrays of equal length (in this case `price`). I'm struggling with how to write this as a single query, and avoiding having *all* of the records being returned for me to locally compute the covariance.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish in two **pseudo**-SQL queries:

```
SELECT
(AVG(price1*price2) - AVG(price1)*AVG(price2)) as covar
FROM data
```

and

```
SELECT price AS price1 WHERE HOUR(timestamp)=1 AND symbol_id=1 LIMIT(MIN(COUNT(price1,price2)))
SELECT price AS price2 WHERE HOUR(timestamp)=1 AND symbol_id=2 LIMIT(MIN(COUNT(price1,price2)))
```

The *first* statement takes two equal length arrays of `price1` and `price2` and computes the covariance. 
The *second* statement is what is selecting two different types, that all take place within the 1st hour of transactions, and limits the returned values to be equal length.

In my limited SQL knowledge, I'm having trouble understanding how I would combine these queries. Any help is much appreciated. *Ultimately being able to run one query that computes the pair-wise covariance for a specific block of time would be lovely.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused here. Covariance is meant to be calculated on simultanously collected data. (Like two measurements made at the same time.) (See e.g. read answer at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/134856)

With the LIMIT clause you drop valuable data, which affects accuracy. Also, I'm not sure about that, but I think, that LIMIT might return different rows at different times, so your calculation might not be determinate.

If you're making covariances by the hour, that means you consider the prices occuring inside an hour to be the same measurements, so I would suggest you calculate the covariance on the average of prices inside that hour.

If you're not considering prices inside the hour to be part of the same measurement, than you have a missing data issue, meaning that you're missing data for price2 when a price1 happened and vice versa. (See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/is-it-possible-to-compute-a-covariance-matrix-with-unequal-sample-sizes)